# Shortest path challenge

Tags: python

This is a question I received as part of the Foobar challenge:

> You're awfullyclose to destroying the LAMBCHOP doomsday device and
>   freeing Commander Lambda's bunny prisoners, but once they're free of
>   the prison blocks, the bunnies are going to need to escape Lambda's
>   space station via the escape pods as quickly as possible.
>   Unfortunately, the halls of the space station are a maze of corridors
>   and dead ends that will be a deathtrap for the escaping bunnies.
>   Fortunately, Commander Lambda has put you in charge of a remodeling
>   project that will give you the opportunity to make things a little
>   easier for the bunnies. Unfortunately (again), you can't just remove
>   all obstacles between the bunnies and the escape pods - at most you
>   can remove one wall per escape pod path, both to maintain structural
>   integrity of the station and to avoid arousing Commander Lambda's
>   suspicions.
>
> You have maps of parts of the space station, each starting at a prison
>   exit and ending at the door to an escape pod. The map is represented
>   as a matrix of 0s and 1s, where 0s are passable space and 1s are
>   impassable walls. The door out of the prison is at the top left (0,0)
>   and the door into an escape pod is at the bottom right (w-1,h-1).
>
> Write a function answer(map) that generates the length of the shortest
>   path from the prison door to the escape pod, where you are allowed to
>   remove one wall as part of your remodeling plans. The path length is
>   the total number of nodes you pass through, counting both the entrance
>   and exit nodes. The starting and ending positions are always passable
>   (0). The map will always be solvable, though you may or may not need
>   to remove a wall. The height and width of the map can be from 2 to 20.
>   Moves can only be made in cardinal directions; no diagonal moves are
>   allowed.

This is the code Foobar says that is taking too much time to execute. How can I make it faster?

**Test cases**

Inputs:

```
(int) maze = [[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Output:

```
(int) 7
```

Inputs:

```
(int) maze = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Output:

```
(int) 11
```

```
def bfs(maze, start_point):
    import collections
    queue_positions = collections.deque()
    queue_positions.append(start_point)
    len_maze = len(maze[0])
    hei_maze = len(maze)
    step_map = [[0 for i in range(len_maze)] for j in range(hei_maze)]
    step_map[start_point[0]][start_point[1]] = 1
    while queue_positions:
        c_pos = queue_positions.popleft()
        if c_pos[1] == len_maze - 1 and c_pos[0] == hei_maze - 1:
            return step_map
        #go up
        if c_pos[0] > 0 and step_map[c_pos[0] - 1][c_pos[1]] == 0 and maze[c_pos[0] - 1][c_pos[1]] == 0:
            step_map[c_pos[0] - 1][c_pos[1]] = c_pos[2] + 1
            queue_positions.append([c_pos[0] - 1, c_pos[1],c_pos[2] + 1])
        #go down
        if c_pos[0] < hei_maze - 1 and step_map[c_pos[0] + 1][c_pos[1]] == 0 and maze[c_pos[0] + 1][c_pos[1]] == 0:
            step_map[c_pos[0] + 1][c_pos[1]] = c_pos[2] + 1
            queue_positions.append([c_pos[0] + 1, c_pos[1],c_pos[2] + 1])
        #go left
        if c_pos[1] > 0 and step_map[c_pos[0]][c_pos[1] - 1] == 0 and maze[c_pos[0]][c_pos[1] - 1] == 0:
            step_map[c_pos[0]][c_pos[1] - 1] = c_pos[2] + 1
            queue_positions.append([c_pos[0], c_pos[1] - 1, c_pos[2] + 1])
        #go right
        if c_pos[1] < len_maze - 1 and step_map[c_pos[0]][c_pos[1] + 1] == 0 and maze[c_pos[0]][c_pos[1] + 1] == 0:
            step_map[c_pos[0]][c_pos[1] + 1] = c_pos[2] + 1
            queue_positions.append([c_pos[0], c_pos[1] + 1, c_pos[2] + 1])
        print step_map
    return step_map

# print bfs(maze, [0,0,1])

def find_certified_pos(maze, step_map, pos):
    count = 0
    len_maze = len(maze[0])
    hei_maze = len(maze)
    least_step = 1 << 31
    for i, j in [[1,0], [-1,0], [0,1], [0,-1]]:
        i2 = pos[0] + i
        j2 = pos[1] + j
        if i2 < 0 or i2 == hei_maze or j2 < 0 or j2 == len_maze:
            continue
        elif maze[i2][j2] == 0:
            count += 1
            if step_map[i2][j2] > 0:
                least_step = min(step_map[i2][j2], least_step)
    if count >= 2 or (pos[0] == hei_maze - 1 and pos[1] == len_maze - 1):
        return least_step
    else:
        return False

def find_shortest_one_move_path(maze):
    len_maze = len(maze[0])
    hei_maze = len(maze)
    step_map = bfs(maze, [0,0,1])
    print step_map
    best_step = step_map[hei_maze-1][len_maze-1]
    print "best" + str(best_step)
    if best_step == len_maze + hei_maze - 1:
        return best_step
    least_step = 0
    answer_step = 1 << 31
    for i in range(hei_maze):
        for j in range(len_maze):
            if maze[i][j] == 1:
                least_step = find_certified_pos(maze, step_map, [i, j])
            if least_step:
                step = bfs(maze, [i, j, 1])
                if step[hei_maze-1][len_maze-1] != 0:
                    answer_step = min(least_step + step[hei_maze-1][len_maze-1], answer_step)
            if answer_step == hei_maze + len_maze - 1:
                return answer_step
    return answer_step
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The easiest way to post code is to paste it into the question editor, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block.

Comment: i have done it please check it

Comment: Welcome to the site: you may want to read [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Comment: @boardrider Note that on Code Review we actually *don't* want just a minimal example. We want the actual implementation, because only then can you see other bad things the OP does. Therefore, there is no link to [mcve] here :)

Comment: Unfortunately, @Graipher, there's no entry in the site's _help_ that shows only the [cve] aspects of [mcve]. I hoped the OP would be smart enough to take the applicable lessons from [mcve] while ignoring the inapplicable ones. Maybe the powers-that-be on codereview.stackexchange.com could adapt the SO [mcve] to a [cve] suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com?